# need help converting anonymous usort function

Tags: php

I recently started hosting a website on 000webhost which doesn't support PHP 5.3 and kept getting the unexpected T_FUNCTION error at the first usort function in this file.

```
<?php
    $cityXML = simplexml_load_file("http://build.uitdatabank.be/lib/1.2/city.xml");
    $regionXML = simplexml_load_file("http://build.uitdatabank.be/lib/1.2/region.xml");
    $headingXML = simplexml_load_file("http://build.uitdatabank.be/lib/1.2/heading.xml");
    $cities = array();
    foreach($cityXML->city as $city)
    {
        $cities[]=$city;
    }
    usort($cities, function($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a['city'], $b['city']);
    });
    $regions = array();
    foreach($regionXML->region as $region)
    {
        $regions[]=$region;
    }
    usort($regions, function($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
    });
    $headings = array();
    foreach($headingXML->heading as $heading)
    {
        $headings[]=$heading;
    }
    usort($headings, function($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
    });
?>
```

I believe it's something to do with the fact that this is an anonymous function and therefore doesn't run on an older version of PHP.

I've looked into using create_function() to help convert it but can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. Can you guys help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a function and use the name of the function instead of the original function:

```
usort($headings, function($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
});
```

for example, would become:

```
usort($headings, "sort_by_title");

function sort_by_title($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
}
```

Comment: `create_function` works on PHP5.2, but it's very memory-inefficient, so you should just create like this answer.